# How to dynamically store index of an array element into a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a photo gallery with multiple galleries listed that I need to paginate.

So, this variable

`$galleries = Photograph::find_by_sql($sql);`

holds an array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Photograph Object
    (
        [id] => 
        [gallery_name] => candies
    )

[1] => Photograph Object
    (
        [id] => 
        [gallery_name] => icecream
    )

[2] => Photograph Object
    (
        [id] => 
        [gallery_name] => pastries
    )

[3] => Photograph Object
    (
        [id] => 
        [gallery_name] => chocolate
    )
)
```

(I've shortened it for convenience)

I'm using these two variables to set a selected gallery:

```
$newest_gallery = reset($galleries);
$gallery_name = (isset($_GET['subj']) ? $_GET['subj'] : $newest_gallery->gallery_name);
```

I was able to set the selected gallery by using the gallery_name, however, I'm unable to paginate the galleries since I need to somehow dynamically store a numerical index of an array element (which holds the gallery_name) into a variable in order to create the pagination function, since I need an integer value for this purpose.
So, I basically need to get the index of an array element. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use key? http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: It's no good. It returns index element. I need index numbers of the array elements. Those numbers in brackets.

Comment: did you read the link at all?

Comment: Yes I did. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here but in my case key returns "id" which is an index element of an array object. Id is no good to me because those are ids of photographs, not the galleries. There are dozens of ids in each gallery. I need to get the index number of each array object. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to make a traverse over the array:

```
## subj is set - search for it in the array of the objects
if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {
  foreach ($galleries as $id => $gallery) {
    if ($gallery->gallery_name == $_GET['subj']) {
       ## we've found a match - note the id and the name
       $gallery_name = $_GET['subj'];
       $gallery_id =$id;
       break;
    }
  }
}
## if subj was not specified or we found no match in the array 
if (!isset($gallery_id)) {
  reset($galleries);
  $gallery_id = key($galleries);
  $gallery_name = $galleries[$gallery_id]->gallery_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your array of galleries and add set the value for id yourself:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($galleries as $gallery){
    $gallery['id'] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```